# Creating dropup menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm creating this site: http://google1.php5.cz/index.html and I need for my menu popup menu.

I want to create this: if I'll point my mouse on the word "ABOUT" the menu will pop up and there will be like 3 choices: something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button) but upside down.

The problem is (like you can see on the page) I can't figure out how to have the poping up block as long as the "ABOUT" block?

Also, I can't use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In the W3 Schools example adding the bottom: 100%; attribute to:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Will make the menu open upwards.

It should look like this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use Javascript, then you can use the CSS [`bottom`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp) attribute to push the dropdown list up, to give it a "dropup" effect.

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vuact43/), where the example code is the same as the w3schools link you provide, with the following addition:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vuact43/

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just perform the following 2 modifications:

1. Add "bottom: 100%" to .dropdown-content in css file to reverse the direction of the pop up menu

   ```
     .dropdown-content {
          bottom:100%;  <!-- <<<THIS WILL MAKE THE MENU OPEN UP INSTEAD OF OPENING DOWN -->

          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          min-width: 160px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }
   ```
2. Change the "min-width: 160px" to "min-width: 100%" to make "the poping up block as long as the "ABOUT" block"

   ```
      .dropdown-content {
          bottom:100%;  
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;

          min-width: 100%;  <!-- <<<THIS WILL MAKE THE POP UP BLOCK AS WIDE AS THE BUTTON -->

          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }
   ```